# For loop in Python somehow exits early

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, break

I am really sorry for the vague title but I don't really know the specifics of what's happening with my code. I am currently learning Python and finding it interesting so far. I am practicing the concept of `generator functions` and wrote a little program that finds palindromes using a `generator function`.

Here is the code (Python 3.6, written in Spyder):

```
def ispalindrome(n):
    #creates a list for storing the element of the number one by one
    l=[]
    #storing the digits
    while n!=0:
        l.append(n%10)
        n=int(n/10)
    #setting useful variables
    i=len(l)-1
    flag=False    
    #traversing the list and checking whether palindrome
    for n in range(0,len(l)):
        #this block is executed only if n is less than (len(l)-1)-n
        if n<i-n:
            #comparing elements
            if l[n]==l[i-n]:
                #flag is set to true everytime l[n] equals l[(len(l)-1)-n]
                flag=True
            else:
                break
        #if n>(len(l)-1)-n
        else:
            break
    #returns the flag    
    return flag

#basic generator function that yields whenever ispalindrome() returns true
def palindromes(n=1111):
    while True:
        if ispalindrome(n): yield n
        n+=1

#traversing through palindromes generator function
for n in palindromes():
    if n>1131: break    
    print('{} is a palindrome'.format(n))
```

When ran I get this output:

```
1111 is a palindrome
1121 is a palindrome
1131 is a palindrome
```

Needless to say the output is completely wrong. I added a few prints in my code and tried to find out the issue and it looks like the program is exiting the for loop inside `ispalindrome()` function early. It is exiting the `for-loop` as soon as it encounters two digits and two ends which match, when this should not be the case. Is it because of the `break` keyword somehow?
I will greatly appreciate if someone can point out what am I doing wrong with this code and how should I approach this correct the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not *exiting* as soon as it finds two digits that match, but it is doing something else wrong.

Comment: A better method: `s = str(n)`, `return s[:len(s)//2] == s[:(len(s) - 1)//2:-1]`

Comment: Great method Harvey! It will significantly reduce my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you've got the idea backwards.

With the current format of your code you should be assuming it *IS* a palindrome and breaking when you discover it is not.

Instead you are assuming it is not, then setting it to "it is" the first time you see equality.  But then the next time you see inequality you merely break without setting it to false again.

If I were to code this I wouldn't bother with a flag, I would merely return "false" the moment an inequality was found.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't right.

By default, you think the number is not a palindrome (`flag=False`), and if you see a mirrored int, you set the flag to true (`if l[n]==l[i-n]: flag=True`).

You should do the contrary. You should set the flag to `True` by default, and if an item is not mirrored, return a flag to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the fellow users, my code was clearly logically in the wrong. I was never setting back flag variable to `False` whenever I was exiting from the for loop. So I took in account the suggestions made and changed my code.
Here is the code following my previous solution with a `flag` variable:

```
def ispalindrome(n):
    #creates a list for storing the element of the number one by one
    l=[]
    #storing the digits
    while n!=0:
        l.append(n%10)
        n=int(n/10)
    #setting useful variables
    i=len(l)-1
    flag=False    
    #traversing the list and checking whether palindrome
    for n in range(0,len(l)):
        #this block is executed only if n is less than (len(l)-1)-n
        if n<i-n:
            #comparing elements
            if l[n]==l[i-n]:
                #flag is set to true everytime l[n] equals l[(len(l)-1)-n]
                flag=True
            else:
                flag=False
                break
        #if n>(len(l)-1)-n
        else:
            break
    #returns the flag    
    return flag

#basic generator function that yields whenever ispalindrome() returns true
def palindromes(n=1111):
    while True:
        if ispalindrome(n): yield n
        n+=1

#traversing through palindromes generator function
for n in palindromes():
    if n>2552: break    
    print('{} is a palindrome'.format(n))
```

And here is the one suggested by both Blusky and Fredman (more efficient than mine to say the least):

```
def ispalindrome(n):
    #creates a list for storing the element of the number one by one
    l=[]
    #storing the digits
    while n!=0:
        l.append(n%10)
        n=int(n/10)
    #setting useful variables
    i=len(l)-1   
    #traversing the list and checking whether palindrome
    for n in range(0,len(l)):
        #this block is executed only if n is less than (len(l)-1)-n
        if n<i-n:
            #comparing elements
            if l[n]!=l[i-n]:
                #flag is set to true everytime l[n] equals l[(len(l)-1)-n]
                return False
        #if n>(len(l)-1)-n
        else:
            break
    #returns the flag    
    return True

#basic generator function that yields whenever ispalindrome() returns true
def palindromes(n=1111):
    while True:
        if ispalindrome(n): yield n
        n+=1

#traversing through palindromes generator function
for n in palindromes():
    if n>2552: break    
    print('{} is a palindrome'.format(n))
```

P.S: I am neither a professional s/w dev nor have I access to high quality courses or a mentor, that's why question boards like stackoverflow is useful for me. I know this is a dumb question and if I thoroughly checked my code again and again I might have realized the mistake, but I don't think it requires a downvote, does it?